# Firefox isn't launching from Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to lauch firefox browser from eclipse using Selenium WebDriver. The console window shows "Launching Firefox" and nothing happens.
What may be wrong?

```
   package testSanity;
import com.openqa.selenium.FirefoxDriver;
import com.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
public class testAdminLogin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Rakesh\\Desktop\\Java_Selenium\\geckod‌​‌​‌​river.exe");
        driver.sendKeys("Click", 12);
    }
}
```

I'm Using selenium-java-3.3.1, have installed geckodriver path in PATH variable of Windows and have installed Firebug and Firepath plugins in firefox. Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Lol.. Where are you trying to sendKeys? You first need to open a webpage and then Identify element using `findElement`. You're missing following command:

```
driver.get("http://www.yourURL.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change order of the lines

1. Geckodriver should be set before driver initialization.

   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\Users\Rakesh\Desktop\Java_Selenium\geckod‌​‌​‌​river.exe");

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Let me know if it works for you